# How to count votes in mySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I have the following mySQL tables:

**Answers**

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------+
| answer_id |  content  | user_id | question_id |   timestamp   |
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|        66 | Blah blah |     101 |          33 | 23/12/13 4:13 |
|        67 | Thank you |     102 |          34 | 23/12/13 12:11|
+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

**Votes**

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| direction | user_id | answer_id | 
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|         1 |     101 |        66 |
|         0 |     102 |        66 |
|         1 |     100 |        66 |
|         1 |     103 |        66 |
|         0 |     101 |        67 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

What I want to do is to select all answers with their respective vote, like so and ORDER BY vote

```
+-----------+------+
| answer_id | vote |
+-----------+------+
|        66 |    2 |
|        67 |    -1 |
+-----------+------+
```

So far, I've got:

```
SELECT answers.answer_id,votes.direction,COUNT(*) AS answer_vote 
FROM answers 
    LEFT JOIN votes ON answers.answer_id=votes.answer_id 
WHERE 
    answers.question_id='61' 
GROUP BY votes.direction
```

I'm quite stumped.

Comment: Using (1, -1) in votes.direction to represent up- and downvote, respectively, would simplify summing votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that:

```
SELECT answers.answer_id,SUM(IF(votes.direction = 0, -1, 1)) AS answer_vote 
FROM answers 
    LEFT JOIN votes ON answers.answer_id=votes.answer_id 
WHERE 
    answers.question_id='61' 
GROUP BY answers.answer_id
```